# Windows 11 Desktop Icon and Taskbar Spacing

Tags: windows-11-v22h2

After I've plugged my device into a 32" Lenovo monitor. I've notice that there is a big gap between my desktop icon and the taskbar. My OS is Windows 11 22H2. After some digging online, I am still unable to resolve this issue.

[image: Windows 11 22H2 with big gap in between desktop and taskbar]

I've done everything I can to make the desktop icon to be smaller, but still, there is big gap in between. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps find a video driver better matched to your monitor - That is what I would suggest here.

Answer (score 1):

Desktop icons spacing is controlled by registry settings, but it's
easier to use the free
[Winaero Tweaker](https://winaero.com/winaero-tweaker/) :

[image]

If you're interested in the required registry settings, click in
Winaero Tweaker the link "See in detail how this tweak works"
which will direct you to the article
[How to change Desktop icon spacing in Windows 10, Windows 8.1 and Windows 8](https://winaero.com/how-to-change-desktop-icon-spacing-in-windows-10-windows-8-1-and-windows-8/?utm_source=software&utm_medium=in-app&utm_campaign=winaerotweaker&utm_content=iconmetrics).